# Register ASP.NET DI Service with parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

As you know there is sample service register in vNext using following code (in startup.cs file):

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
```

The AuthMessageSender class is like this

```
public class AuthMessageSender : IEmailSender, ISmsSender
{
    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task SendSmsAsync(string number, string message)
    {
        // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

What if we need this class like this

```
public class AuthMessageSender : IEmailSender, ISmsSender
{
   //Added lines to class
   private readonly object_something
   public AuthMessageSender (object something){_something=something}

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task SendSmsAsync(string number, string message)
    {
        // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

In this scenario how can I register service using **AddTransient** method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to provide a registration for the other service.

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
services.AddTransient<ISomething, Something>();
```

Or, if using a primitive datatype such as string:

```
services.AddTransient(x => new AuthMessageSender(something: "MyString"));
```